# Fuseki web app - blank page after installation

Tags: web-applications, fuseki

I've installed Fuseki as a web app as per this guide:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-webapp.html#fuseki-web-application

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 and Tomcat9. /etc/fuseki is writeable and in the Tomcat admin panel everything seems to be fine. The Tomcat log files show me no errors.

According to this quick start guide:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-quick-start.html

I should be able to see the UI and be able to click on "Add one". But... I see nothing. Just a blank page. What am I missing? Any guess why I can't see the UI that lets me start using Fuseki? Is there some step missing in the documentation of the quick start guide?

**UPDATE**

It seems like the link on the Fuseki website provides a WAR package without the SPARQL UI (the webapp folder is empty and doesn't contain the frontend). I ended up just using the Docker package stain/jenna-fuseki instead. I'll leave this question up though because I didn't really find an answer - so not sure if the quickstart guide is just wrong/missing something or there was a mistake on my end.